# ArcPy to Enable Database for use with Data Reviewer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, data-reviewer

Has anyone ever used ArcPy to Enable Data Reviewer? By this I mean add the necessary feature dataset and tables to an existing geodatabase in order for it to be considered a Reviewer workspace and store Data Reviewer results. The Sytax Provided by ESRI is such: 
EnableDataReviewer_Reviewer (workspace, {spatial_reference}, {register_as_versioned}, {config_keyword})

I got the code from this location:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-reviewer-toolbox/enable-data-reviewer.htm

When I use it however, I am getting this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EnableDataReviewer_Reviewer'

I am using Arc 10.2.2, not sure if that has something to do with it. Please let me know if you have any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the error you receieved

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'EnableDataReviewer_Reviewer'

occurs in (at least) three situations.

1. You don't have Data Reviewer installed - Data Reviewer is a separate install of ArcGIS Desktop; it is not installed by default.
2. You don't have a Data Reviewer license - it appears that the command `arcpy.CheckOutExtension("datareviewer")` doesn't feed back that there isn't a license available when it can't find one
3. You are running your arcpy using 64bit Background Geoprocessing.  My `arcpy` scripts typically default to using 64bit geoprocessing - `C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4` - and some tools are only available using the 32bit `arcpy`.

Switching to 32bit `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4` on a PC that has Data Reviewer installed, and where I have a license available, the code from your linked webpage worked flawlessly.